# Getting Automation Error Excel VBA trying Update SQL Db

Tags: sql, excel, vba, automation

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'On Error GoTo ErrExit
    
    Dim cn_ADO As ADODB.Connection
    Dim cmd_ADO As ADODB.Command
        
    Dim SQLUser As String
    Dim SQLPassword As String
    Dim SQLServer As String
    Dim DBName As String
    Dim DbConn As String
    
    Dim SQLQuery As String
    Dim strWhere As String
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim jOffset As Integer
    Dim iStartRow As Integer
    
    Dim strItmId As String
    Dim strParentItm As String
    Dim strName As String
    Dim strValu As String
    Dim strDateCreate As String
    Dim strDateUpdate As String
    
    jOffset = 1
    iStartRow = 9
    i = iStartRow
    
    SQLUser = "sa"
    SQLPassword = "xxx"
    SQLServer = "xxx"
    DBName = "TEST"
    
    DbConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & SQLUser & ";Password=" & SQLPassword & ";Initial Catalog=" & DBName & ";" & _
            "Data Source=" & SQLServer & ";User Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;" & _
            "Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"
            
    Set cn_ADO = New ADODB.Connection
    cn_ADO.Open DbConn
    
    Set cmd_ADO = New ADODB.Command
    
    While Cells(i, jOffset).Value <> ""
        strItmId = Cells(i, 0 + jOffset).Value
        strName = Cells(i, 2 + jOffset).Value
        strValu = Cells(i, 3 + jOffset).Value
        
    strWhere = "ItmId = " & strItmId
    
    SQLQuery = "update COCFG " & _
                "set " & _
                "[Name] = '" & strName & "', " & _
                "[Valu] = '" & strValu & "', " & _
                "where " & strWhere     (AUTOMATION ERROR POINT, SYNTAX ISSUE AT 'where')
                
    cmd_ADO.CommandText = SQLQuery
    cmd_ADO.ActiveConnection = cn_ADO
    cmd_ADO.Execute
    
        i = i + 1
    Wend
        
    
    Set cmd_ADO = Nothing
    Set cn_ADO = Nothing
    
    Exit Sub

'ErrExit:
'            MsgBox "Error: " & Err & " " & Error(Err)
'            Application.StatusBar = False
'            Application.Cursor = xlDefault
'
'            If Not cn_ADO Is Nothing Then
'                Set cn_ADO = Nothing
'            End If
'            If Not cmd_ADO Is Nothing Then
'                Set cmd_ADO = Nothing
'            End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sql syntax error, try `"[Valu] = '" & strValu & "' " & _` - no comma before `where`. Attention. Your code is subject to Sql injection.

Comment: Wow!!!!!!  I cannot believe that was the prob!!!!!!!  I'm new so its understandable, THANK YOU!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: BTW - What do you mean by SQL Injection?

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is a security vulnerability to users inserting malicious SQL statement into data fields for execution. The defence is to use placeholders (?) in the query and put the values into parameters.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cn_ADO As ADODB.Connection, cmd_ADO As ADODB.Command
    Dim dbConn As String
    Dim strItmId As String, strName As String, strValu As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, jOffset As Integer, iStartRow As Integer

    Const SQLUser = "sa"
    Const SQLPassword = "xxx"
    Const SQLServer = "xxx"
    Const DBName = "TEST"

    Const SQLQuery = " UPDATE COCFG " & _
                     " SET [Name] = ?, [Valu] = ? " & _
                     " WHERE [ItmId] = ? "

    dbConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=" & SQLUser & _
             ";Password=" & SQLPassword & ";Initial Catalog=" & DBName & ";" & _
             "Data Source=" & SQLServer & _
             ";User Procedure for Prepare=1;Auto Translate=True;Packet Size=4096;" & _
             "Use Encryption for Data=False;Tag with column collation when possible=False"
            
    Set cn_ADO = New ADODB.Connection
    cn_ADO.Open dbConn
   
    Set cmd_ADO = New ADODB.Command
    With cmd_ADO
        .CommandText = SQLQuery
        .ActiveConnection = cn_ADO
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50) ' 50 size
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
       .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P3", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
    End With

    jOffset = 1
    iStartRow = 9
    i = iStartRow
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        While .Cells(i, jOffset).Value <> ""
            strItmId = .Cells(i, jOffset).Value
            strName = .Cells(i, jOffset + 2).Value
            strValu = .Cells(i, jOffset + 3).Value
            cmd_ADO.Execute n, Array(strName, strValu, strItmId) ' parameter values
            i = i + 1
        Wend
    End With
        
    Set cmd_ADO = Nothing
    Set cn_ADO = Nothing
    
End Sub
```